# Iterate through two lists at same index

Tags: list, prolog

How can you iterate through two lists with the same index, so that you get a pair of each list:

```
?- X = [1, 2, 3], Y = [a, b, c], ...
ElemX = 1,
ElemY = a;

ElemX = 2,
ElemY = b;

ElemX = 3,
ElemY = c.
```

Comment: If you need to also perform some kind of operations on the pairs, take also a look to `maplist/3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through both lists simultaneously:

```
member2(E1, [H1|T1], E2, [H2|T2]) :-
    member2_(T1, T2, H1, H2, E1, E2).

member2_(_, _, E1, E2, E1, E2).
member2_([H1|T1], [H2|T2], _, _, E1, E2) :-
    member2_(T1, T2, H1, H2, E1, E2).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- member2(E1, [1, 2, 3], E2, [a, b, c]).
E1 = 1,
E2 = a ;
E1 = 2,
E2 = b ;
E1 = 3,
E2 = c.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pairs_keys_values/3` as if it was a zip() function:

```
?- X = [1, 2, 3],
   Y = [a, b, c],
   pairs_keys_values(Pairs, X, Y).

Pairs = [1-a, 2-b, 3-c].
```

And then iterate through that.

Comment: This is not showing the results in the way that the question requested.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the point of the exercise is to figure out how to do this on your own rather than using built-in predicates, it doesn't seem like it should be any more complicated than

```
zip( [X|_ ] , [Y|_ ] , X:Y ) .
zip( [_|Xs] , [_|Ys] , X:Y ) :- zip(Xs,Ys,X:Y) .
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`nth0(?Index, ?List, ?Elem)`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth0/3):

```
_X = [1, 2, 3], _Y = [a, b, c], nth0(_Index, _X, ElemX), nth0(_Index, _Y, ElemY).
```

Comment: this takes the diagonal of a square `_X x _Y` while still enumerating all the lower triangle of that square, throwing away all the elements which lie below the diagonal. but we only need the diagonal. IOW this does the enumeration as in nested sequential loops, `for (i,x) in indexed(X): for (j,y) in indexed(Y): if j==i: yield (x,y)`; but we really need the looping done "in parallel" i.e. in unison: `for x in X and y in Y: yield (x,y)`. (all "code" in pseudocode).

Comment: Still nice. Much less effort.

Comment: @false not unless this is run in a prolog which is capable of running it in linear (or linearithmic) time - or less, IMO.

Comment: O(N)-runtime-wise you are right. But `nth0(+integer,+list,?)` is pretty fast in current systems like Scryer, Trealla, and even SWI. So we would have to agree on the average value of the index first to make a relevant statement.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested all the three answers on SWI Prolog and added one which uses `maplist/3`.
The code is the following

```
member2(E1, [H1|T1], E2, [H2|T2]) :-
    member2_(T1, T2, H1, H2, E1, E2).

member2_(_, _, E1, E2, E1, E2).
member2_([H1|T1], [H2|T2], _, _, E1, E2) :-
    member2_(T1, T2, H1, H2, E1, E2).

pair(A,B,(A,B)).

test_member2(Size):-
    length(L0,Size),
    length(L1,Size),
    findall((A,B),member2(A, L0, B, L1),_).
   
test_pkv(Size):-
    length(L0,Size),
    length(L1,Size),
    findall(P,pairs_keys_values(P, L0, L1),_).

test_nth0(Size):-
    length(L0,Size),
    length(L1,Size),
    findall((X,Y),(nth0(Index, L0, X), nth0(Index, L1, Y)),_).

test_maplist(Size):-
    length(L0,Size),
    length(L1,Size),
    maplist(pair,L0,L1,_).
```

Here the results:

```
?- time(test_member2(10000)).
20,014 inferences, 0.024 CPU in 0.024 seconds (100% CPU, 847596 Lips)

?- time(test_pkv(10000)).
10,016 inferences, 0.019 CPU in 0.019 seconds (100% CPU, 519172 Lips)

?- time(test_nth0(10000)).
60,013 inferences, 0.352 CPU in 0.352 seconds (100% CPU, 170474 Lips)

?- time(test_maplist(10000)).
20,006 inferences, 0.014 CPU in 0.014 seconds (100% CPU, 1462905 Lips)
```

Comment: The intended input is 2 lists, not a *Size*. The intended output is an element at the same position of each list, backtracked, rather than a *list*. These are not fair tests.

Comment: Also the value 10000 is highly disputable. Why not perform such tests for 10^E, E in 1..5?